# ServerTooBusy Exception on Emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

While i was running the silverlight application on my device, it is actually going on fine.
But, when i try to run it on the emulator, it shows me

> *ServerTooBusyException was unhandled*
>
> The HTTP service located at "the ip address with web service link
>   here" is too busy

it also pointed to the file named :

> reference.cs

Personally i am extremely new to this project as they left over. I had totally no idea where to start to look for the source of problem coming from. I had also gone through the web trying to browse for some information about this exception. But, i don't seem to quite understand them (kind of confusing for me).

I also took some advice from my colleagues which is to change the IP address of the computer. But it doesn't seem to work.

The web service is hosted in the same LAN but different PC. The code was developed in C#. The web service are WCF.

1. So, my question here is where should i start to troubleshoot the source of problem?
2. What would be cause of the problem while it run fines on device but not on the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by installing Fiddler. This program will show you which data is actually being sent between your computer and the WCF endpoint. The errors returned are not always directly related to the real problem is my experience with WCF.

Comment: I can access the WS through IE from my comp but not the emulator.

Comment: So fiddler is not picking up the data? You have to make sure it uses the fiddler proxy. Look at this post http://peterkellner.net/2011/04/25/getting-fiddler-to-see-you-wcf-traffic/ and this one http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jan/14/Monitoring-HTTP-Output-with-Fiddler-in-NET-HTTP-Clients-and-WCF-Proxies

Post a bit more of what is going wrong if you need more help.

Comment: seems like no traffic is going out from the emulator to the WCF. What could it possibly blocking it ? I had turned off the firewall.

Comment: I found the source of problem, it was the proxy settings on the IE browser.